# Unrecognized commands in chapters using report document class

Tags: errors, texstudio

I'm getting 'unrecognized command' errors in my chapter_1.tex file when using the following directory structure (using TeXstudio)

- Report

  - chapters

    - chapter_1.tex
  - main

    - main.tex

with the following code.

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
    \def\input@path{{../chapters/}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Test Chapter}
    \label{chap:chapter_1}
    \input{chapter_1}
\end{document}
```

**chapter_1.tex**

```
% !TeX root = ../main/main.tex
\begin{align}
    1+1&=2 \\
    2+2&=4
\end{align}
```

Here, I get 'unrecognized command' errors with `align` because chapter_1.tex does not have `\usepackage{amsmath}`, which I can't include because chapter_1 is essentially within the document. It also does not automatically indent or autocomplete properly.

Everything compiles just fine, but I'd like to know how to get rid of these errors. In my actual files I have many such errors, so it's quite bothersome.

---

**Edit: Found a "fix"**!

The problem happens only if you have a fresh TeXstudio session (i.e. if you properly exited each individual file shown in the tabs above the editor). So with a fresh session,

1. Open the `main.tex` *and* the `chapter_1.tex` files. You should(?) see my problem mentioned in this post.
2. Now, close the entire TeXstudio session *without* first exiting the individual files.
3. Open either `.tex` file again. The problem should now be fixed in `chapter_1`.

Notes: If you open another chapter file after step 3, for example `chapter_2.tex`, the problem will exist for `chapter_2.tex` until you do steps 2-3 again. Also, if you close `main.tex` (the file with the packages) and try to exit and restart your TeXstudio session then any chapters that you kept open will have the problem again. `main.tex` must always be open before exiting the session.

Good enough for me.

Comment: You can compile either file to make the document. Compiling the files works for me too, but the problem is the 'unrecognized command' error. Do you get the same error? In TeXstudio `\begin{align}` and other parts in `chapter_1.tex` are highlighted in red, indicating an error, and hovering the mouse over the highlighted error displays the 'unrecognized command' message. When I use many packages and many environments, none of which auto-indent or auto-complete, these errors become a problem.

Comment: I tried restoring default settings, it didn't work. Yep, the very same MWE. If you try to type a second `align` environment in `chapter_1`, does the new environment auto-complete `\begin{align}` with an `\end{align}`? The problem isn't compiling, the problem is when I want to type the contents of each chapter.

Comment: So I would say your issue is the following: when you "freshly" open  `chapter_1.tex` only (i.e. without TXS knowing about `main.tex`, what's not the case when you open a sub-file by clicking on the file-tree in the left panel), TXS doesn't know about `amsmath` being loaded and thus do not activate its `.cwl` for autocompletion and syntactic checking. Doing as you explain solves this issue. Note the difference between opening last *file(s)* and opening last *session*.

Comment: `@ebo` I originally thought that everything would be fixed when you compiled. Is the preamble not always part of the compile process? Going by what you said, it looks like if you have `main.tex` already open when you start a new TXS session, and _then_ you open `chapter_1`, you actually do get auto-complete features in `chapter_1` because the `.cwl` was activated as you say. However, you will still see the `unrecognized command` errors even after you compile. To get rid of all errors,  both files must be pre-open when starting a new session. Is this strange? Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Found a "fix"**!

The problem happens only if you have a fresh TeXstudio session (i.e. if you properly exited each individual file shown in the tabs above the editor). So with a fresh session,

1. Open the `main.tex` *and* the `chapter_1.tex` files. You should(?) see my problem mentioned in this post.
2. Now, close the entire TeXstudio session *without* first exiting the individual files.
3. Open either `.tex` file again. The problem should now be fixed in `chapter_1`.

Notes: If you open another chapter file after step 3, for example `chapter_2.tex`, the problem will exist for `chapter_2.tex` until you do steps 2-3 again. Also, if you close `main.tex` (the file with the packages) and try to exit and restart your TeXstudio session then any chapters that you kept open will have the problem again. `main.tex` must always be open before exiting the session.

Good enough for me.

Answer (score -1):

I realise this is an old question, however when I came up against this problem the provided fix did not help.

An alternate solution to the one above is to ensure that when you are loading in packages, instead of loading them in like;

```
\usepackage{amsmath,latexsym,color,graphicx,amssymb,here}
```

load them in one at a time;

```
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{latexsym}    
\usepackage{color}    
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}    
\usepackage{here}
```

this seems to immediately fix the issue.

Comment: This seems like a bizarre fix, since `\usepackage{A,B,C}` is similar to `\usepackage{A} \usepackage{B} \usepackage{C}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm not sure how this relates to the question.